# Bot and whale protection

Tags: solidity, uniswap, openzeppelin

I would like to deploy a smart contract and add some liquidity on uniswap, but I'm afraid that some whales or bots will suck up all of my tokens as soon as the liquidity pool is created.

What is the best practice to avoid that?
And what would be an appropriate max token amount for one wallet to hold, to prevent whales?

Thanks very much in advance.